# Not able to use manipulated attribute of javascript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like so:

```js
{
    ...,
    receiptsDetailsList: {
        Jan: [{}],
        Feb: [{}]
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to manipulate the objects in the month arrays like so:

#### Call to function

```js
this.transformToWebReceipt(this.receipts).then(newReceiptsDetailsList => {
        this.invoice.receiptsDetailsList = newReceiptsDetailsList;
        console.log(this.invoice.receiptsDetailsList);
        Object.values(this.invoice.receiptsDetailsList).forEach(receipts => {
          // undefined here
        console.log(receipts[0].image);
        })
        //this.invoiceGenerator.createPdf(this.invoice);
      });
```

#### Function

```js
transformToWebReceipt(receiptsData) {
    let newReceiptsData = receiptsData;
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      Object.values(newReceiptsData).forEach((receipts: any) => {
        receipts.forEach(receipt => {
          this.imagesDb.getReceiptImagesByReceiptId(receipt.mobileReceiptId).then((img: any) => {
            if (img !== undefined) {
              receipt.image = img.picture;
            }
          });
        });
      });
      resolve(newReceiptsData);
    });
  }
```

When I then try to console.log the receipt.image after the manipulation, I get undefined no matter what I do. Yet I can see in the DevTools that Image was set. I do have the 'values below was evaluated just now' on DevTools. Am I doing something wrong setting the object?

Comment: I believe forEach is returning a copy of each receipt, not a reference. Try using a `for(let i = 0; i < receipts.length; i++)` loop and access the receipts by `receipts[i]` and see if it works.

Comment: I'll give that a try there and let you know :). Thnks

Answer (score 1):

`this.imagesDb.getImgById` is an asynchronous function. That means that it will run in the background while your code continues running. The `.then` indicates that the function will be run after it's finished running. Therefore, if you want to use the contents of the function, put everything inside the `.then` or use an asynchronous function.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: Hi, I updated my code above. I have the edits in the .then() field but I'm still getting undefined?

Comment: The `resolve(newReceiptsData);` is outside the `.then` in your `transformToWebReceipt` function, which means you resolve before receiving the data.

Comment: If I put it into the images DB call, wouldn't it resolve too early though :/?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `forEach` when dealing with promises as it's not promise aware
`this.imagesDb.getReceiptImagesByReceiptId` is an asynchronous function that returns a promise which means any code after this function ex:`console.log(receipt.image)` will run while your `getReceiptImagesByReceiptId` is taking it's natural time to return the promise. hence why you get `undefined`
to fix this you have to use `receipt.image` inside `then`, or return the new values in a new object/array variable

So your code should look like this

```
const returnimage = async (receiptsDetailsList)=> {
   imgob={}
 Object.entries(receiptsDetailsList).forEach(async (receipts: any) => {
        imgob[receipts[0]]=[]
      for (let i = 0; i < receipts[1].length; i++) {
         var finalvalue=imagesDb.getImgById(receipts[1][i].mobileReceiptId).then((img: any)=>{
          if (img !== undefined) {
            imgob[receipts[0]].push(receipts[1][i].image = img.picture)
            }
          if (img !== undefined) {  imgob[receipts[0]].push(0) }
          else {   imgob[receipts[0]].push(img) }  
             return imgob
          })
        }
        finalvalue.then(o=>{
          console.log(o)
        })
     })
    }
    returnimage(receiptsDetailsList)
```